# iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement (using Adobe AIR)

Tags: ios, air, iphone-5, appstore-approval

I keep receiving the following message from Apple when submitting my app for approval:

"iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. New iPhone apps and app updates submitted targeting iOS 6 and above must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images."

I'm using AIR SDK 3.9 (and I checked to make sure by tracing NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion).

I have a Default-568h@2x.png image in the src folder, and I checked the Project/Properties/ActionScript Build Settings/Package content (I'm using Flash Builder 4.6). It is definitely checked off to be included in the build. In "Export Release Build", I don't see it in the Package Contents there, but I don't see any of the other Default png's either, so I don't think that's the problem.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm compiling with Flash Builder, so I don't need to use XCode. And trust me, I checked the spelling of the file name half a dozen times after the first one didn't work.

Comment: Well, you weren't understanding my comment, but I was wrong anyway...

Comment: Are you using Xcode or not? If so what version of Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the launch images also located in the folder "bin-release-temp"... I have to put them manually into that folder...

Comment: http://rohitdhore1612.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/air-invalid-binary-iphone-5-optimization-requirement-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5/

Answer (score 0):

The launch images cannot be referenced **anywhere** in the project. You cannot embed them. You cannot use them. If you do, they are not packaged as launch images, but as images used at runtime. I was having the same problem when I was referencing the images as a `SplashScreenImage` source. It's an unfortunate way for it to be handled, basically requiring you to include the same image twice, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help. It describes what and where to keep default images in air application for iPhone deployment.

http://rohitdhore1612.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/air-invalid-binary-iphone-5-optimization-requirement-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5/